# i want to include jquery file into cakephp ctp file

Tags: cakephp

```
<?php echo $html->js( 'jquery.min' ); ?>
```

i have kept js file in webroot/js/jquery.min.js

iam getting error

Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::js does not exist [CORE\cake\libs\view\helper.php, line 142]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min');
```

Comment: now shows Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Html [APP\views\my_files\index.ctp, line 6]

Comment: which cakePHP version are you using

Comment: well, HtmlHelper should have been included by default, but if you get that error, then try adding Html in your var $helpers array in controller

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use

```
<?php
echo $scripts_for_layout;
?>
just before you </head>.
```

Result: all js files from js folders will automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include js file in ctp page please check this code this will helping to you.

```
echo $this->js->link('jquery-1.10.1.min');
```

Output:

```
<a href="/cake/posts/jquery-1.10.1.min" id="link-1138978643">/cake/posts/jquery-1.10.1.min</a>
```

Try this :

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.10.1.min');
```

Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cake/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```